# Preflight errors in Kubernetes installation

Tags: linux, kubernetes, installation, ubuntu-18.04, kubeadm

I am referring to the following link [Installation Link](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-kubernetes-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux) for installing Kubernetes on Ubuntu 18.04. I am getting the following errors on typing the command :

```
sudo kubeadm join 192.168.0.114:6443 --token qgce4f.tgzda1zemqnro1em --discovery-token-ca-cert-hash sha256:6ebc15a5a9818481f8a98af01a7a367ba93b2180babb954940edd8178548773a ignore-preflight-errors=All

W0303 18:33:39.565868    7098 join.go:185] [join] WARNING: More than one API server endpoint supplied on command line [192.168.0.114:6443 ignore-preflight-errors=All]. Using the first one.
[preflight] Running pre-flight checks
    [WARNING SystemVerification]: this Docker version is not on the list of validated versions: 18.09.3. Latest validated version: 18.06
[preflight] Some fatal errors occurred:
[ERROR DirAvailable--etc-kubernetes-manifests]: /etc/kubernetes/manifests is not empty
    [ERROR FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-kubelet.conf]: /etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf already exists
    [ERROR Port-10250]: Port 10250 is in use
    [ERROR FileAvailable--etc-kubernetes-pki-ca.crt]: /etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt already exists
[preflight] If you know what you are doing, you can make a check non-fatal with `--ignore-preflight-errors=...`
```

Can someone please tell me how to fix this? Thanks !

Comment: Can you remove/backup `/etc/kubernetes/manifests` directory content, `/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf` and  `/etc/kubernetes/pki/ca.crt` files as it is telling files are already exist. I think master(kubeadm --init) is up, can you list token and see output `kubeadm token list`

Comment: Are you running the `kubeadm join` on the other machine? If so you can clean `/etc/kubernetes` or install k8s again.

Comment: You can try `kubeadm init` to undo a prior join.

Answer (score 5):

Consider using the `kubeadm reset` command as described [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/setup-tools/kubeadm/kubeadm-reset/):

```
The "reset" command executes the following phases:

preflight              Run reset pre-flight checks
update-cluster-status  Remove this node from the ClusterStatus object.
remove-etcd-member     Remove a local etcd member.
cleanup-node           Run cleanup node.
```

**The fourth phase of this command should fix the 4 errors you mentioned:**

A ) It will stop the kubelet service - so port `10250` will be released.

B ) It will delete contents of the following directories:

```
    /etc/kubernetes/manifests 
    /etc/kubernetes/pki
```

C ) It will delete the following files:

```
    /etc/kubernetes/admin.conf 
    /etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf 
    /etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf 
    /etc/kubernetes/controller-manager.conf 
    /etc/kubernetes/scheduler.conf
```

(*) Make sure you run the `kubeadm join` command with verbosity level of 5 and above 
  (by appending the `--v=5` flag).